# Using multiple firewalls cause ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony 2.3.4 and I tried to set up multiple firewalls. But now everytime I go to /admin/login there's error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.These are my routing.yml and security.yml files:

routing.yml

```
login_admin:
    pattern:   /admin/login/
    defaults:  { _controller: HerbanistAdminBundle:Security:login }

login_check_admin:
    pattern:   /admin/login_check/

logout_admin:
    path:   /admin/logout/

login_customer:
    pattern:   /customer/login/
    defaults:  { _controller: HerbanistStoreBundle:Security:login }

login_check_customer:
    pattern:   /customer/login_check/

logout_customer:
    path:   /customer/logout/
```

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: admin, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        admin_secured_area:
            pattern: ^/admin
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                login_path: /admin/login
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /admin
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin
        customer_secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/customer
            form_login:
                check_path: /customere/login_check
                login_path: /customer/login
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /customer
            logout:
                path:   /customer/logout
                target: /customer

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/customer, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

---

**Edit**

Debug messages in Profiler:

```
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
INFO - Matched route "login_admin" (parameters: "_controller": "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController::urlRedirectAction", "path": "/admin/login/", "permanent": "true", "scheme": "null", "httpPort": "80", "httpsPort": "443", "_route": "login_admin")
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener::onKernelException".
INFO - Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point (A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.)
DEBUG - Calling Authentication entry point
DEBUG - Listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener::onKernelException" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.exception".
DEBUG - Listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException" was not called for event "kernel.exception".
DEBUG - Listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException" was not called for event "kernel.exception".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse".
DEBUG - Write SecurityContext in the session
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ChromePhpHandler::onKernelResponse".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse".
```

Comment: Is there debug toolbar output you can trace (and/or reproduce here) to make it easier to find out what the issue is?

Comment: If you mean Logs in Profiler, there are 20 lines of Debug messages. Should I post them all?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a Symfony 2 user. If you think they might add some context, or give some clues as to the problem, post what you believe is most relevant. 20 lines doesn't sound excessive to me.

Comment: So debug toolbar output is now also in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `anonymous: ~` to both of your firewalls and force the required roles in the `access_control` section. Read the [*Security* chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) for more information.

Comment: What do you mean by "force the required roles"? Roles in access_control are already defined.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict was that paths in routing.yml and security.yml are not in exactly the same URL format. In routing.yml they are ending with '/', but in security.yml they don't. So the solution is to end each path with '/'. And also to add `anonymous: ~` to both firewalls.