# Symfony 4 - two firewalls cause ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am writing this because previous answers to [Using multiple firewalls cause ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594014/using-multiple-firewalls-cause-err-too-many-redirects-in-symfony-2) have not been helpful. "Main" firewall seem to work just fine, "Admin" is the one causing problems. Every time I try to enter the path "http://localhost:8000/admin" it redirects to"http://localhost:8000/admin_login" as it should, but goes into redirect loop and crashes with the error named above.

security.yaml

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
providers: 
    chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, db_provider]
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
               theadmin:
                    password: iamadmin
                    roles: 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'
    db_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    admin:
        pattern: /admin
        anonymous: ~

        form_login: 
            username_parameter: _username
            login_path: /admin_login
            check_path: /admin_login
            provider: in_memory
            default_target_path: admin

        logout:
            path: /admin_logout
            target: /


    main:
        pattern: /
        anonymous: ~

        form_login: 
            username_parameter: _email
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login
            provider: db_provider
            default_target_path: welcome

        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
access_control:
- { path: ^/welcome, roles: ROLE_USER }
- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/admin_login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

AdminSecurityController.php

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class AdminSecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin_login", name="admin_login")
     */

    public function admin_login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $utils)
    {
        $error = $utils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        $auth_checker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');

        if ($auth_checker->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
            return $this->render('admin/dashboard.html.twig', [
                'controller_name' => 'AdminController',
            ]);
                } else{
                    return $this->render('admin_security/admin_login.html.twig', [
                        'error' => $error
                    ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin_logout", name="admin_logout")
     */

    public function admin_logout()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access control entries are analyzed from [the top to the bottom](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html). So, you need to place the `^/admin_login` entry before the `^/admin`.

Imagine how the security component is currently set:

1. You visit the login form then press submit
2. You (guest) are redirected to the `/admin_login` path
3. Security component goes through the entries and matches the **/admin**_login to the `^/admin` entry
4. Because it requires `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`, you thus end up with a loop

Remember to clear the cache afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But now I keep getting also redirected to /admin_login instead of /login even when I visit /welcome

Comment: Regarding the comment above, all works perfectly now. It appears I accidentally removed" admin" from pattern: /admin

Comment: Glad I could help.